# Connect Open vSwitch to interface in a VM OpenStack

Tags: openstack, openvswitch

I have single VM in OpenStack, with a single interface eth0.
I want that all the traffic that goes in and out is passed trough a Open vSwitch (where I will have some flow rules).

I did the following:

```
ovs-vsctl add-br br0
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0
```

(Connection here would be interrupted)

```
ifconfig eth0 0
dhclient br0
```

Now this works if I try with Ubuntu on my machine, but it doesn't in the OpenStack VM. Even if I set the ip and route of br0 manually.

Any idea of why this happens?